# how to count the days passed in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, printing, dataset

i have the following dataframe

```
    Datetime
0   2022-06-01 00:00:00
1   2022-06-01 00:01:00
2   2022-06-01 00:02:00
3   2022-06-01 00:03:00
4   2022-06-01 00:04:00
5   2022-06-01 00:05:00
```

that it is year-month-day
i want to count what day is
or example
for tje 2022-06-01 i want to have a variable that will be equal to day= days of january + days of february + ... + one day of june ..
the same for the 2022-06-02 ..
untill a final date
does anybody knows what i've got to use in order to do that?

Comment: Do you need day of year? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571275/calculate-day-of-year-in-dataframe-from-a-datetime-column-to-another-column-in-p ?

Comment: the code above that editor proposed to me to see does not calculate all the days of my code

Comment: that code calculates only two of the 110 days in my code

Comment: It is weird, are all values datetimes?

Comment: i want to calucalte all the days among the time frame of my datafrmae

Comment: yes , all values are datetimes

Comment: So working for 110 days and then not? Can you explin what means `not working` ?

Comment: well, 
my initial datetime is 2022-06-01 and the final is 2022-10-10 (year-month-day)
and i want for each datetime to know what day of the year is 
for example i want to know that 2022-06-01 is the 152nd day of the year ( may i am wrong in my calculation)

Comment: Can you explain what means `not working` ?

Comment: what do you mean with your question?

Comment: `that code calculates only two of the 110 days in my code` Can you explain it?

Comment: oh sorry i was wrong ...i ment i want to calculalte for the dates that exist in my datetime dataframe

Comment: `.i ment i want to calculalte for the dates that exist in my datetime dataframe` - not understand, can you explian what is problem?

Comment: will.. i have the first datetime in my dataframe 
2022-06-01 ...i need a variable that representes which day of the year is the 2022-06-01 (the 152nd day of the year)
then for 2022-06-02 that is the 153nd day of the year ...untill the final datetime in my dataframe that is 2022-10-10 i want to know that this is the 283rd day of the year..

Comment: OK, use `df['DOY'] = df['Datetime'].dt.dayofyear`

Comment: data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':pd.to_datetime(['2022-06-01', '2022-10-10'], format='%Y-%m-%d')})
# calculate day of year
data['DOY'] = data['datetime'].dt.dayofyear
that is what i've done and at the outpout i have only for the two dates in which day they correspond 
what i mean is 
 datetime DOY
0 2022-06-01 152
1 2022-10-10 283
how can i edit my code in order to have DOY for all of my values

Comment: Not understand. What is expected output from `data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':pd.to_datetime(['2022-06-01', '2022-10-10'], format='%Y-%m-%d')}`

Comment: yes my code is wrong 
i want to edit my code in order to have like an output the following 
Datetime                                 doy
0   2022-06-01 00:00:00         152
1   2022-06-01 00:01:00         152
2   2022-06-01 00:02:00         152
3   2022-06-01 00:03:00         152
4   2022-06-01 00:04:00         152
5   2022-06-01 00:05:00         152 
          .
          .
      2022-10-10 23:59:00        283